# Python JSON form Post datas

Tags: python, json, forms, python-requests

I want to post a form using Python an request, that form uses JSON

Here is the JSON datas that are sent when sendind the form :

```
{"method":"PostMessage",
"params":["6drsebmMzn0xYSogAfd_X4DojKa7OpR9QDYAH41lm80xMYjL225zOeeYow5it1l6TCsiOrGb6cvbU50hN11EzkJF9gtlZ3Wgk3ipOO1zOKdcrFFKIudz-ct95EogJSNu",{"ownerId":256887569,"id":18642094,"type":2},{"posterName":"Lionel",
"isPrivate":false,
"posterUrl":"",
"posterEmail":"monemail@gmail.com",
"body":"Good photos !!"}],
"id":0}
```

My question is how to send this data using python and requests ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is this:

```
import requests

# generate data as string (you may want to automate this line)
data = '{\"method\":\"PostMessage\",\"params\":[\"6drsebmMzn0xYSogAfd_X4DojKa7OpR9QDYAH41lm80xMYjL225zOeeYow5it1l6TCsiOrGb6cvbU50hN11EzkJF9gtlZ3Wgk3ipOO1zOKdcrFFKIudz-ct95EogJSNu\",{\"ownerId\":256887569,\"id\":18642094,\"type\":2},{\"posterName\":\"Lionel\",\"isPrivate\":false,\"posterUrl\":\"\",\"posterEmail\":\"monemail@gmail.com\",\"body\":\"Good photos !!\"}],\"id\":0}'

# post
r = requests.post(url, data=data)

# print result
print r.text.encode('utf-8')
```